# Installing dashlet in Alfresco 3.4

Tags: share, dashboard, alfresco

I am trying to install the Site Blog dashlet (and others) from the Extras site 
http://code.google.com/p/share-extras/wiki/SiteBlogDashlet
The build works ok.

However, I am unable to see the dashlet on the dashboard configuration. I tried copying the jar file to tomcat/shared/libs and to tomcat/lib and restarted the server, but to no avail.

There are no error messages in the catalina log, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Anyone got this to work with V3.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're looking into the correct dashboard configuration? Bear in mind that **site dashlets**, like the one you're up to, are not the same as user dashlets, meaning that while the former are only available within a Site Dashboard configuration (i.e. **configuring the dashboard after entering a site**), the latter are found into the User Dashboard configuration.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. Creating a site indeed and customising the dashboard on the site indeed loaded the dashlet. I'll need to polish up on my Share concepts and I'm now well on my way, thanks to you.